# Hibernate search elasticsearch schema management NONE still connects to elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm looking into moving our hibernate search implementation from file-based lucene indices to elasticsearch, but am confused about the documentation. Specifically, for the index schema management strategy NONE:

> The index, its mappings and the analyzer definitions will not be created, deleted nor altered. Hibernate Search will not even check that the index already exists.

We want to remove the startup dependency of hibernate search (so it won't try and query elasticsearch at startup). Reading the schema management strategies indicates that NONE should do that.

However, looking at the implementation of the code, I can see that it still explicitly checks if the index exists:

```java
if (this.schemaManagementStrategy == IndexSchemaManagementStrategy.NONE) {
    this.schemaCreator.checkIndexExists(this.actualIndexName, this.schemaManagementExecutionOptions);
    return false;
}
```

I would've expected that this didn't happen. When I entered a purposely incorrect host to connect to, server startup still fails with:

```
 Request:
========
Operation: IndicesExists
URI: registryreference
Data:
null
Response:
=========
null
    at org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.client.impl.JestClient.executeRequest(JestClient.java:188) ~[hibernate-search-elasticsearch-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
... (omitted rest of stack) 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

We are using hibernate search 5.6.5 and elasticsearch 2.4.6.

Comment: even when not checkign the index schema, it expects to prepare a pool of connections for indexing and query works. Could you describe more of your use case, and how you expect to control when it's safe to finally try to establish connections?

Comment: Hi @Sanne , we would rather updates/queries fail at runtime because elasticsearch is down rather than having the web servers/batch jobs fail to start because we are unable to start the server, which has happened to us in the past. The index not being available is not critical for us and should not prevent us from being able to reboot the application if needed - we can always re-index if we have to after a downtime.

Is it not possible to prepare the connection pool separately from checking if the index exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug: [HSEARCH-2568](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-2568).

It was fixed in Hibernate Search 5.7.0.Final, so upgrading should do the trick. You will have to upgrade Hibernate ORM to version 5.2 as well, though. If you go down this route, I would advise to upgrade directly to Hibernate Search 5.11 and ORM 5.4, the most recent versions in which quite a few bugs have been fixed.

Be aware that, as @Sanne mentioned, even if Hibernate Search does not send a query to the Elasticsearch cluster, it might still create a pool of TCP connections. Maybe you can tell us more about your use case so we can help?

Comment: we did look at upgrading but are blocked by the queryDSL project unfortunately and are still stuck with 5.1, at least in the short-medium term. Is there any chance of a backport to 5.6?

Comment: That's unlikely, unless someone volunteers: Search 5.6 is quite old, and ORM 5.1 is not even maintained anymore. Maybe we'll do one last release at some point, but it's clearly not a priority right now.